# Handle back button pressed in BaseGameActivity or SurfaceView

Tags: android, events, back-button, pressed

When I created my MainActivity class, I change the "extends" to extends BaseGameActivity to implement Google+ login. There are some downsides to this. I can no longer handle `onBackPressed()` and `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)`. This kind of sucks.

Fixing onTouchEvent was easy. My game uses SurfaceView which can take touch input. But for onBackPressed, I cannot simply do this.

Anyone know how to handle back button pressed events. I saw there was a `onKeyDown()` method in both surfaceview and basegameactivity but from prior experience, I'm pretty sure that is only for devices with API version 5 and older, right? Someone know how to do this?

Comment: What mean backpress is not working?

Comment: onBackPressed() is not a method in the BaseGameActivity, meaning, when the back button is pressed on the users device, onBackPressed() is not called because it is only in Activity, not BaseGameActivity.

Comment: can you post this BaseGameActivity

Comment: I got the code from google, it's a standard for signing in with Google+  Here it is: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils                                It may be interesting to note that the BaseGameActivity class extends FragmentActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
is not called because it is only in Activity
```

You are actually using the support version of the `Activity` which is the `FragmentActivity` which you can call `onBackpressed` programatically.

**sample:**

You can create a method for onBackPress functionality and call it whenever you want. But Also I really think that it should be called upon pressing the back button because it is a support version of activity means it extends from `Activity` under the hood of it.

```
BaseGameActivity.this.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: But I don't want to call on it, I want the user's android device to call it when the user presses the back button so I can handle the event

Comment: @vedi0boy it is impossible that its not called. try to clean and build and run the app

Comment: Oh wow this is embarrassing. Sorry about that, when I pressed CTRL+SPACE to see the methods, I didn't see the `onBackPressed()`. That was a dumb mistake, thanks for your help!

Comment: @vedi0boy happens sometime to, you are welcome. Happy coding. :))

Comment: thx! I guess I should have looked at the java docs as extra reference before posting here